# How To make a small flash when a button is tapped?

Tags: android, eclipse, button

So I'm making an android app that has more than 100 buttons,but you know when you tap a button normally when you don't changed the background or anything it flashes orangish color. However since I've added a background color to my buttons when they're tapped it just goes to the next screen and you can't tell that you've tapped a Button!

Could someone help me please?
Sorry if I don't know what those are called:(

Comment: Your design sounds counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare in drawables this selector and name it for example: button.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btnPressed"/>
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/btnNormal"></item>

</selector>
```

android:drawable can be color, image, another drawable...
And then you can declare your button as:

```
<Button 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/button"
     />
```

If you create your buttons in code you can call method: setBackgroundResource() and pass resource id.
Example:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Eh, you meant button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);

Comment: Yes i did do this but when i run the app on the emulator the button are huge sizes!

Comment: Yes it the images anyone know what dimensions i should use?

Comment: You should use 9-patch images for buttons. Take a look at this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: it has to be there. If you can't find then try to download SDK again from Android web site.

Comment: draw9patch.bat (if you are using Windows) is located inside Android SDK tools folder. Try to locate Android SDK folder. If you don't remember where that folder is you can find path in Eclipse by going to Window->Preferences->Android and SDK Location field should be path to your SDK folder.

Comment: Thank you alot Emran, by the way are you arab? I am :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    alphaDown = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.3f);
    alphaUp = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1.0f);
    alphaDown.setDuration(1000);
    alphaUp.setDuration(500);
    alphaDown.setFillAfter(true);
    alphaUp.setFillAfter(true);
    analyse.startAnimation(alphaUp);
```

try this code on your button click

Comment: Where do i put it where in button click

Comment: Sorry about this but im a noob could someone show a easier way?

Comment: just put these lines under onClick event of the button nothing else

Comment: `public void onClick(View arg) {
    AlphaAnimation alphaDown = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.3f);
    AlphaAnimation alphaUp = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1.0f);
    alphaDown.setDuration(1000);
    alphaUp.setDuration(500);
    alphaDown.setFillAfter(true);
    alphaUp.setFillAfter(true);
    arg.startAnimation(alphaUp); }` this is what he means

Answer (score 0):

Use [android selectors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). Create new drawable with its own states and set it as button's background drawable